# How to set List<String> into RecyclerView adapter for ImageView on Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my application i want show images into `RecyclerView` **Adapter**.
I write below codes, but not show me any images into ImageView.

**My Adapter codes :**

```
public class DetailMiniGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailMiniGalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> model;
    private Context context;

    public DetailMiniGalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> model) {
        this.context = context;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public DetailMiniGalleryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row_detail_mini_gallery, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DetailMiniGalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(Constants.SERVER + model)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(viewHolder.listRow_detailMiniGalleryImg);
        Log.e("galleryImages", model+"");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return model.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView listRow_detailMiniGalleryImg;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            listRow_detailMiniGalleryImg = view.findViewById(R.id.listRow_detailMiniGalleryImg);
        }
    }
}
```

**My images url in LogCat :**

```
/galleryImages: [/img/ps/1.png, /img/ps/2.png, /img/ps/3.png, /img/ps/4.png, /img/ps/5.png]
```

**I fill adapter with this code in mainActivity :**

```
miniGalleryAdapter = new DetailMiniGalleryAdapter(getActivity(), detail.getImage());
```

But when use this code : `.load(Constants.SERVER + model.get(0))` show me image but just show **1image**! i want show **all of images**.

how can i it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `model` directly in load , use `model.get(i)`

```
 Glide.with(context)
            .load(Constants.SERVER + model.get(i)) //< i is position of item
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
            .into(viewHolder.listRow_detailMiniGalleryImg);
```